# Want to continue running the calculator after the answer

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

```
def add(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2

def sub(n1, n2):
    return n1 - n2

def mul(n1, n2):
    return(n1 * n2)

def div(n1, n2):
    return n1 / n2 

def pow(n1, n2):
    return n1 ** n2

operations = {
    "+ = Add": add,
    "- = Subtract": sub,
    "* = Muliply": mul,
    "/ = Division": div,
    "** = Power": pow
}

try:
    num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

    for sym in operations:
        print(sym)

    operator = input("Pick an operator from the line above: ")

    if operator == "+":
        answer = add(num1, num2)
        print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
    elif operator == "-":
        answer = sub(num1, num2)
        print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
    elif operator == "*":
        answer = mul(num1, num2)
        print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
    elif operator == "/":
        answer = div(num1, num2)
        print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
    elif operator == "**":
        answer = pow(num1, num2)
        print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
    else:
        print("Enter a valid operator.")
except ValueError:
    print("Enter valid inputs.")
```

Want to write a statement to continue running the calculator after the answer is shown as output. Example, 2.0 + 2.0 = 4.0

I want the code to ask 'Do you want to continue operations with 4? Type 'y' for yes and 'n' for no.'
And then let's say I enter the multiply operator again, and another number to do the calculation with, it should show, 4.0 * 2.0 = 8.0

Comment: Wrap everything in your `try` in `while True:` and track the value of your calculation above the `while True:`...an unbroken loop is how you continue the iteration, but you need to track your calculation value outside of the loop so it doesn't reset. You are very close to this, I would try to see if you can solve it with that idea before looking for someone to write it for you

Comment: I tried to write the code, but when I break the while loop, how do I make the program ask if the user wants to continue again? And how do I display the current answer they have the first time they continue and other following times? The code is in the answers

Comment: Okay, @DhruvSinghroha I have posted an answer to your issue. Please try to understand why it works this way, as stated you were very close.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as stated in the comments to your original question, you were super close. All you needed to do is wrap your logic in a loop so you can iterate over the items, which I do in my example below with a `while True` loop. Then outside of that loop, you needed to track a value that the user creates...for example:

```
def add(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2

def sub(n1, n2):
    return n1 - n2

def mul(n1, n2):
    return(n1 * n2)

def div(n1, n2):
    return n1 / n2

def pow(n1, n2):
    return n1 ** n2

operations = {
    "+ = Add": add,
    "- = Subtract": sub,
    "* = Muliply": mul,
    "/ = Division": div,
    "** = Power": pow
}

try:
    # track this value out of loop so it isn't reset
    tracked_value = None
    # make a continuous loop...
    while True:
        # anything here will reiterate unless broken
        # tracked_value will always be none unless the user opts to reuse it below...
        if tracked_value is None:
            num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        else:
            # now we can turn num1 into the tracked value, the user wishes to reuse it
            num1 = tracked_value
            print(f'You opted to reuse the tracked value for number 1, which was: "{num1}"')

        # always will be asked.
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

        # print options
        for sym in operations:
            print(sym)

        operator = input("Pick an operator from the line above: ")

        # honestly I would alter your dict to remove the need for
        # this huge conditional, but I didn't want to change too much
        # ex: method = operations.get(operator, None)... if method not None: answer = method(num1, num2)

        if operator == "+":
            answer = add(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        elif operator == "-":
            answer = sub(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        elif operator == "*":
            answer = mul(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        elif operator == "/":
            answer = div(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        elif operator == "**":
            answer = pow(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        else:
            print("Enter a valid operator. Try again...")
            # 'continue' so you don't hit the code below, this starts the loop again
            continue

        # now logic is done, ask if they wish to continue or break
        should_continue = input(f"Do you want to continue your calculation with your current answer: '{answer}'? "
                                "Type 'y' for yes and anything else for no. ")

        # logic to continue or not, remember continue starts the iteration over
        if should_continue.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
            # assign the tracked value now the user wants it.
            tracked_value = answer
            continue
        else:
            print('Thanks for using my calulator. See you next time.')
            # break out of the while loop, the user opts to exit.
            break

except ValueError as ex:
    print(f"Enter valid inputs: {ex}")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def add(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2

def sub(n1, n2):
    return n1 - n2

def mul(n1, n2):
    return(n1 * n2)

def div(n1, n2):
    return n1 / n2 

def pow(n1, n2):
    return n1 ** n2

operations = {
    "+ = Add": add,
    "- = Subtract": sub,
    "* = Muliply": mul,
    "/ = Division": div,
    "** = Power": pow
}

def calculator():

    try:
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

        for sym in operations:
            print(sym)

        operator = input("Pick an operator from the line above: ")

        if operator == "+":
            answer = add(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        elif operator == "-":
            answer = sub(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        elif operator == "*":
            answer = mul(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        elif operator == "/":
            answer = div(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        elif operator == "**":
            answer = pow(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operator} {num2} = {answer}")
        else:
            print("Enter a valid operator.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter valid inputs.")

calculator()

should_continue = input("Do you want to continue your calculation with your current answer? Type 'y' for yes and 'n' for no. ")

if should_continue == 'y':
    should_continue = True
else:
    should_continue = False
    print("Thank you for using the calculator.")

while should_continue:
    calculator() 
    break
```

Comment: Please only use the answer box to post a complete answer to your question. Per your comment, above, this is a 'work in progress', not an answer, so it would be better to add it as such with an [edit] to your question.